# Единица Rem CSS

Tags: css, css3, sass, less

У меня такой случай:
Проект верстаю на rem.
Rem, на сколько я знаю, от значения `font-size` родителя html.
К примеру у меня `font-size:62.5%` в `index.css`
Почему когда я делаю к примеру `font-size 30%`  ничего не меняется?
`width` и `heith` блоков остаются такими же.

Comment: Попробуй изменить font-size у непосредственного родителя и посмотри что получится

Comment: @santavital Ничего не поменялось(

Comment: Не совсем понял вопрос, если честно. Относительно чего ты считаешь %? Rem -  это единица, которая задает размер относительно корневого элемента - HTML. Какой размер шрифта у HTML стоит?

Answer (score 0):

> Почему когда я делаю к примеру font-size 30% ничего не меняется?

Уберите минимальный размер шрифта в настройках браузера. 
Но не факт, что у тех, кто будет пользоваться вашим сайтом, будет такая же настройка.
И вообще, за шрифт меньше 10 пикселей надо отрывать разработчику руки.